# ¿Hay algún problema si se crea una contraseña que contiene carácteres especiales para usuarios de Linux?

Tags: linux

Estoy usando un generador de contraseñas que por su fortaleza deseo incluya carácteres especiales no alfanuméricos (`#`, `!`, `?`, `%`, entre otros) para asignarles a usuarios en sistemas operativos de la familia Linux (especialmente Ubuntu y Linux Mint).

Estos usuarios tendrán acceso a algunas operaciones en modo `root` por lo que deberán intoducir su contraseña en la terminal para la mayor parte de su trabajo.

¿Existe algún problema al realizar operaciones en la terminal si las contraseñas cuentan con estos carácteres especiales?

Comment: Hola, no olvides marcar alguna de las respuestas como aceptada, de lo contrario tu pregunta quedará como no resuelta. Si ninguna de ellas ha solucionado tu inquietud, coméntalas

Comment: No se si haya algún problema con los "caracteres especiales" los cuales nadie ha definido exactamente en las respuestas, pero mucho mejor que utilizar caracteres que podrían ser dificiles de ingresar o recordar (o posiblmente ser incompatibles, si es que se da el caso) es utilizar passphrases que simplemente consiste en utilizar como contraseña una frase bastante mas larga pero fácil de recordar (Fuente: Edward Snowden https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzGzB-yYKcc o XKCD: http://xkcd.com/936/ )

Comment: Alguno ha intentado instalar ultimamente ubuntu.
Cuando pones en la contraseña caracteres especiales como [# , ni siquiera te los deja poner en el campo de contraseña al inicio de sesion. version 17.04
En la instalación te lo acepta correctamente pero luego no puedes acceder.
Alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta donde yo se, no existe ninguna restricción con respecto a los caracteres especiales al momento de generar las contraseñas en los sistemas basados en Unix.

---

### Ubuntu

En la documentación de Ubuntu con respecto a [Strong Passwords](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StrongPasswords) recomiendan el uso de caracteres especiales para su generación. Cito y traduzco la parte pertinente:

> 1. Minúsculas (a, b, c, etc.)
> 2. Mayúsculas (A, B, C, etc.)
> 3. Numéricos (0, 1, 2, etc.)
> 4. Caracteres especiales (@, %, !, etc.)

Lo mismo debería aplicar para Linux Mint ya que ambos derivan de Debian.

---

### Red Hat

En la documentación sobre [Password Security](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-wstation-pass.html) también recomiendan el uso de caracteres especiales para la generación de contraseñas. Cito y traduzco:

> Incluir caracteres especiales no alfanuméricos tales como &, $, y > puede mejorar en gran medida la seguridad de la contraseña

---

### Slackware

En la documentación [Basic Security](http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:security:basic_security) no mencionan específicamente el uso de caracteres especiales pero recomiendan el uso de varios caracteres para aumentar la complejidad. Cito y traduzco:

> Complejidad: Mientras mayor sea la variedad de los caracteres, mayor será la seguridad de la contraseña.

---

En conclusión, no tengas miedo de usar caracteres especiales ya que es una buena práctica incluirlos en la generación de los mismos.

Answer (score 2):

Teóricamente, no debería de haber ningún problema; es más, cuantos más simbolos más segura es la contraseña.

Pero ten cuidado con la distribución del teclado, a veces linux viene con la distribucion en_US y la <kbd>@</kbd>, entre otros, cambia de posicion.

[image: Teclado qwerty inglés]

Comment: Podrías aportar una fuente oficial que confirme tu respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Precisamente para una mayor fortaleza en cuanto a seguridad, se sugiere usar caracteres especiales, no hay restricción.

Aunado a los caracteres especiales, también se sugiere usar palabras minúsculas (a, b, c, etc.), Mayúsculas (A, B, C, etc.), númericos (0, 1, 2, etc.)

ver mas información aquí :
[Caracteres especiales en password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100683/special-characters-in-password) (inglés)